# Render image & text on jsp page using spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, outputstream

I have to show some details on jsp page along with image which is saved on my computer drive.

How can I achieve it using Spring MVC?
I have tried the following way but it is not working(yeah, my written code is wrong)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/detailsPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView viewAPIs(@RequestParam("id") Long id, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("detailsPage");
    if (apiId != null) {
        Details obj = detailsService.getObjById(id);
             try {

                   String fileName = obj.getStructurePath();             
                   OutputStream  outputStream = res.getOutputStream();
                   InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
                   int readBytes = 0;
                   byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
                   while ((readBytes = is.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) != -1) {
                         outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                   }
                   outputStream.close();
                   is.close();
                   // add outputString to model and show it is on page
                   mav.addObject("structure", outputStream );
             } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
             }
             mav.addObject("obj", obj);
             return mav;
    }
    return null;
}
```

JSP:

```
<div class="type"> 
   <p>Structure</p>
   <div><img alt="img" src="${structure }"/></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do minimal changes an make it work, you should do Base64 encoding of your image and than change the tag as follows

```
<img alt="img" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${structure }"/>
```

So the change in your method should be

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/detailsPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView viewAPIs(@RequestParam("id") Long id) throws Exception {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("detailsPage");
    if (apiId != null) {
        Details obj = detailsService.getObjById(id);
        try {

            String fileName = obj.getStructurePath();
            byte[] binaryData = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(fileName));
            byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64(binaryData);
            String base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64, "UTF-8");
            // add outputString to model and show it is on page
            mav.addObject("structure", base64Encoded);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mav.addObject("obj", obj);
        return mav;
    }
    return null;
}
```

both IOUtils and Base64 are from org.apache.commons, shouldn't have a problem finding

Comment: Thanks @Master, it is throwing "out of memory" error

Comment: I have updated memory param, now it is working fine. Thanks @Master!